# Date_format return false when seconds are leading without zero

Tags: php, date, format

I have a string coming in json message like this: "2016-2-16 13:48:**3**"

Note that the seconds are not leading with zero, and I need to validate that the date is in a correct format before inserting it into a database,

So I created a function to validate the date using date_format function like this:

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s')
{
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);       
    if ($d) {
        return $date;        
    } else {
        return null;
    } 
}
```

My problem when the seconds are not leading with 0 it return null, since the format does not have seconds without leading 0, so it the seconds should be like "03" instead of just "3",

Any ideas?

Comment: First things first: Why are there seconds without leading zeros?

Comment: Main question is: "2016-2-16 13:48:3" is a valid datetime? I suspect no. BTW, to validate that date, you have to manipulate `$date` before validate it. You can try a  `preg_replace( '/:(\d)$/', ':0\1', $date )`

Comment: That was going to be my question. php's date format manual page only has 's' for seconds with leading zeros. 
Do you have any control over the json that you are consuming? If not, you will have to process the date yourself.

Comment: Please satisfy my curiosity: in original json there are also dates with sec > 9, right?

Comment: @fusion3k: Yes when there is a second greater than 9 there will be no problem, so my problem is just when the seconds are less than 10

Comment: @Tyr: it is strange but the json is coming from a client which create his date using javascript functions like getSeconds which return seconds without leading zero

Comment: @MohanadKaleia minutes are with leading zero? Also strange that php DateTime accepts month w/out leading zero with format `m` (=with leading zero), but not for seconds!

Comment: @fusion3k also the minutes are coming without leading zero, but if I fixed the seconds, we can fix the minutes in the same way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't fix the JSON, I'd use a  preg_replace to substitue out single digit seconds and minutes manually--should be easy as you're just padding a `0` to the front of each.

Here's how you could replace the seconds:

```
 $pattern = '/:(.)$/';
 $fixed_seconds = preg_replace($pattern, ':0${1}', "2016-2-16 13:48:3");
 echo $fixed_seconds;
```

For minutes you can use this pattern:

```
 $pattern = '/:(.):/';
 $fixed_minutes = preg_replace($pattern, ':0${1}:', "2016-2-16 13:4:03");
```

Then, if those two get Change your format string to this:

```
$format = 'Y-n-j G:i:s'
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little complicated, but does the job:

```
$date = "2016-2-16 13:48:3";

$dateArray = explode(":", $date);

$newDate = array();

foreach ($dateArray as $splitDate) {
    if (strlen($splitDate) == 1)
        $newDate[] = "0".$splitDate;
    else
        $newDate[] = $splitDate;
}

$date = implode(":", $newDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Date formatting is only prepared for using seconds with initial zeros (option s), so I guess you would need to do something like this:

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s')
{
    $crackedDate = explode(':', $date);
    $newDate = '';
    foreach($crackedDate as $datePart) {
        if (strlen($datePart)==1) {
            $newDate .= '0'.$datePart;
            continue;
        }
    }
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $newDate);       
    if ($d) {
        return $date;        
    } else {
        return null;
    } 
}
```

There is not known format for non initial zero format for seconds or minutes in php dates, so solution ends up being custom function like this, so this is a workaround that could not work with all dateTime formats, just the problem one and a few others, remember that there are a bunch of options for the date formatting

Comment: I guess you meant `strlen` instead of `len`, latter doesn't exist in PHP as far as I'm aware...

Comment: @webeno... you are completely right, I am sorry, I made this by mobile not tested

Answer (score 1):

Very strange date format!
I think that the only way is to preprocess `$date`. The “smell” is that your function support multiple format validation.

I suggest you this way:

```
function validateDate( $date, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s' )
{
    $date = preg_replace( '/:0+(\d{2})/', ':\1', str_replace( ':',':0',$date ) );

    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);     
    if ($d) {
        return $date;        
    } else {
        return null;
    } 
}
```

(Edit: changed regex to match minutes)